# VSCode: How to reduce the margin/gap between text and the cell boundary in Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

In VSCode, there is a large gap between text in a cell and that cell's left-most boundary/edge.

You can see this blank margin or gap in this screenshot, in between the two red arrows:
[image]

There is so much padding here it looks like a 2 or 3-space indent. I would rather have no padding, or at least significantly reduced padding.

Is there any way I can adjust this margin width?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is to left-align with the "ML", I think the answer is "No"